# Finding all errors in Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. How do I find all cpp files with compiler errors? When I build solution, the compiler hits a file with error, then VS will declare the project build failed, and proceed to other projects. So I get only one of the errors.

When I use makefile to build, I could attempt to compile all modified files, then mark all the failed one. Can't Visual Studio do the same?

========

What I mean is that, I have a large project that has files a.cpp, b.cpp, c.cpp, in which I know b.cpp and c.cpp have errors. When VS builds the project, it detects error in b.cpp, then VS will not try to compile c.cpp. The build output is:

```
------ Build started:
a.cpp
b.cpp
"xx\xx\xx\b.cpp": error xxx: xxx
Done building project "project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Building stops before compiler touches c.cpp.

And I found that this only happens in my large projects. In my small project VS will invoke compiler on all cpp files. The usual scenario is when I refactor some headers, I need to build the project again and again, fixing one cpp file at a time.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT question edited

Comment: It is quite strange. And please try to delete bin and obj folder. Or you could [share a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us which could help us troubleshoot the issue quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Build the solution "F6", then look at your error list Menu *View -> Error List* (alternatively, Ctrl + W, E). Then make sure under your error list tab, make sure "Entire Solution" is selected.  This will list all of the compiler known errors and warnings within your project. As far as using makefile, you would have to debug within your Makefile specifically.

To answer your second question, unfortunately, there is no such
thing as a makefile debugger to examine how a particular rule is being evaluated or a
variable expanded, etc. Instead, most debugging is performed with simple print statements and by inspection of the makefile itself.  This isn't handled by VS.

[image]